# Configure Visual Studio Azure cloud service project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm looking to host a CMS-driven ASP.NET web application using Azure cloud services.

I'm new to Azure but have successfully managed to configure a basic Visual Studio project and publish it to an Azure web role from Visual Studio.

The application I'm building will have a very specific configuration where the IIS default web site will itself contain multiple IIS applications, each configured with physical path pointing to the same directory as the main website.

So what I'd like to know is, can this kind of setup be configured within the Visual Studio project. If so, can anyone explain how? If not, how can I ensure that my auto-scaling web roles all adopt the correct IIS configfuration?

Answer (score 1):

By using the Sites element within the service definition file, ServiceDefinition.csdef, you can configure your web role to support multiple websites and web applications. This is accomplished using the sites, applications, and virtual directories features in Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0. These features enable each web role in Azure to support configuration for multiple websites and applications.
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433110.aspx

Hope this helps.

-Nithin